# IRC/XMPP web-based chat client or BNC?

Tags: debian, linux

Is there any webchat client with a daemon for Raspbian/Raspberry Pi? Something like [webpidginz](http://www.shaorang.com/webpidginz/) or an alternative for it. I found it hard to use with Raspberry Pi/Raspbian (because it doesn't provide an ARM version for their plugin.)

Is there any better and lightweight webchat client/BNC for Raspbian? (I don't want use irssi or a terminal based clients also).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should think any linux chat client should work - try [Pidgin](http://pidgin.im/) ([installing FAQs](https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Installing%20Pidgin)) or [Empathy](https://live.gnome.org/Empathy).

Performance will be an issue though, the GUI will probably be slow to respond. (I would therefore recommend [Finch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/finch) (essentially Pidgin for the terminal), but you've said you don't want a terminal client.

Comment: I know I can use pidgin (I said webpidingz is also available). I want to find a web based solution like https://github.com/thedjpetersen/subway ... (also with supporting for XMPP)

Comment: Oh. I didn't quite understand, you want the interface entirely in a browser. I can't really help you there then.

Comment: Something like a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BNC_(software).  Well, pidgin can do that, but is not very usable and effecient :)

Comment: @Ebrahim always a plan! ;)

Comment: @Ebrahim Have you thought about the possibility of running a program such as Pidgin/Finch on another server/raspberry pi and SSHing into it?

Comment: I am already using this method :) I wanted to know is there better solution (also I searched a lot) but seems is not! Well, I think best solution for me is http://www.shaorang.com/webpidginz/ anyway.

Comment: Thanks. My main problem was this http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4474 and now I can use your method!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correct; you want an always-on IRC bouncer, with web-based IRC client to connect & use.

As an IRC bouncer, I would recommend **ZNC** any day, it's feature-complete, uses 1mb~ of RAM most of the time, also has a very nice Web GUI for settings. Plus it's very easy to install.

I'm using it with my a desktop client (Quassel), if you want there are plenty of java-based IRC clients (I wouldn't recommend one because I didn't use any of them), pick one, upload it to your Pi and serve it from there. (using, nginx?) At the end of the day, you'll have a complete BNC server and a web-based IRC interface.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answer. ZNC (only BNC I ever know) is great but is hard to configure :( I've found https://github.com/mfinkle/webclient and https://github.com/kylef/znc-xmpp but I really lazy to learn how to use them :( Could you put a tested step-by-step guideline for compile and using these on Raspberry Pi? It will be so useful for everyone IMHO

Answer (score 0):

I haven't try them, but you can try the following softwares.

## Single user chat

Single user chats allow you to chat with one or more people that you have in your friend list. Some known clients are Pidgin, Gajim, or GTalk.

Some web-based examples:

- [Jappix](https://project.jappix.com/)
- [JWchat](http://stefan-strigler.de/jwchat/) (discontinued)

## Multi user chat (aka MUC)

MUC are clients allowing you to join different rooms and chat with people you don't necessary know. A well known MUC client is IRC (not XMPP).

Some web-based examples:

- [Candy](http://candy-chat.github.com/candy/)
- [MUCkl](http://stefan-strigler.de/muckl/) (discontinued)
- [Speeqe](https://github.com/thepug/speeqe) (discontinued)

If you manage to install one of them, please [share your experience by asking and answering a new question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: None of them is related to the question (a deamon/bot like BNC with ability to access it through your browser), you can test! But thanks for answer :)

Comment: Well... I'm not sure to understand your question :) You want to be able to chat on XMPP network through a web interface, or I'm totally wrong?

Comment: Sorry. I want be always online through my Raspberry Pi :D That is what http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BNC_(software) doing and subway can https://github.com/thedjpetersen/subway ! :)

Answer (score 0):

[subway](https://github.com/thedjpetersen/subway) is migrated from MongoDB and now can be used easier on Rasbian.