# TightVNC copy/paste between local OS and Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, vnc

My TightVNC Server on Raspberry Pi seems can not handle copy/paste between its and my local clipboards. What can I do?

Answer (score 36):

First install autocutsel (`sudo apt-get install autocutsel`)

Then open your /home/pi/.vnc/xstartup (`nano /home/pi/.vnc/xstartup`) and put **`autocutsel -fork`** on it like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
autocutsel -fork
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &
# Fix to make GNOME work
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
/etc/X11/Xsession
```

Then it will work after restart of the vnc server

To Stop VNC Server:

```
vncserver –kill :1 (pick your display)
```

To Start VNC Server:

```
vncserver :1 –geometry 1024x600 –depth 24
```

[Source](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=23521)

Comment: Perfect solution, thank you very much (reboot was required)

Comment: @sweetlilmre, no, reboot not required if you manually run `autocutsel -fork`

Comment: I have an Odroid running Ubuntu Mate 16.04.  I had an odd issue that this fixed.  I could cut and paste from emacs to an xterm within the same VNC server.  And I could cut and paste from an xterm to another app running on the host (which happens to be a Mac).  But I could not cut and paste from emacs to an app on the Mac.  Running autocutsel -fork fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had to make sure my autocutsel comes FIRST in the xstartup for copy/past to work

```
# Makes copy/past work - must come before RANDR 'fix'
#vncconfig -iconic &
autocutsel -s CLIPBOARD -fork
autocutsel -s PRIMARY -fork

# Get's rid of RANDR missing errors
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
/etc/X11/Xsession
```

Comment: May I direct you to the [formatting section of our help center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)?

Comment: Didn't need to be first on my Pi 3. The solution from @Ebrahim above worked (after I remembered to install autocutsel)

Answer (score 0):

Though this is an old post, I ran into an issue where I could no longer copy and paste from host to client with one of my rpi's (I have 5).

I tried everything suggested here and everywhere else I searched but nothing worked.  In the end what worked is this.

1. Logged into the pi,
2. ls /home/pi/.vnc
3. I see 2 files with the dns name of my pi  **mypi:1.log** and **mypi:1.pid**
   I had a thought that there must be a mypi:0 and maybe this was causing the copy/paste to no longer work.
   I don't know all the ins and outs but by connecting to **mypi:1** as the host name with my VNC client I can now copy and paste between host and client again!

I hope that this helps someone else and if anyone has any info to share about this please do!