# tightvncserver and autocutsel not starting via xstartup

Tags: vnc

The solution posted here:

[TightVNC copy/paste between local OS and Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4474/tightvnc-copy-paste-between-local-os-and-raspberry-pi?newreg=56840e49131842d087fe6f4a2aea73f5)

seems like the solution to make sure you can copy and paste between the host and the client, however, the only solution that works for me is to run the 'autocutsel -fork' command from a terminal.

Are there any other obvious issues that I'm missing regarding xstartup?  Permissions on xstartup?

It would seem that xstartup isn't executing, since my cursor is still an X, unless I use the 'xsetroot -solid grey -cursor_name left_ptr'.

tightvncserver is started in rc.local, as per:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=169021

Comment: As per the hundreds of similar posts the advice is to **NOT use rc.local**. Any reason why you aren't using RealVNC

Comment: You can't use RealVNC if using in a commercial application, as I understand it.  If there is a canonical way to start tightvnc, please let me know.

Comment: If you search my old posts you will find a systemd service to start TightVNC

Comment: See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/39374/8697